# What is need of Reducer?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Why Map and Reducer are separate? Why Everything can not be done in Mapper phase.

What are the benefits of separating these tasks. What are the disadvantages of not doing everything in mapper phase or reducer phase.

Comment: Please explain what all you think that can be done in a mapper that you find the reducer is pointless for. There are instances when a Reducer is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Since data are too big to be moved into a single machine for computing, we are using distributed systems to have the work done. In this scenario each computer locally processes a slice of data, after that, in someway we need to collect all the data from each computer and build again a "whole" new file.

Usually a single MapReduce job does not complete the work. You have to execute several MapReduce jobs to get the work done.

The Map phase is all about to process the data locally, the reduce phase is all about to grab all the intermediate results from all computers and join them together into a new "whole file".

Sometime map is enough, sometime it is not. If you have to extract some fields from the data, Map is enough. If you want to sort the file, Map is is not enough.

Paradigm is:
Process locally (MAP) then merge/join all the intermediate results into a new "whole file" (REDUCE).